# Pause TimerTask when android device is locked and resume back when it is unlocked

Tags: android, timertask

I have set my timer as below.

```
Timer t;
TimerTask task;
t = new Timer();
t.schedule(task, 10000);
task = new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            finish();

            try {
                t.cancel();
                t = null;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    };
```

Everything works fine now. My issue starts when android device get locked. Timer continues when device locked. I want to pause my timer when device get locks and resume back when it is unlocked.

Thank you, in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try below code

```
@Override
protected void onPause()
{
super.onPause();

// If the screen is off then the device has been locked
PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
boolean isScreenOn = powerManager.isScreenOn();

if (!isScreenOn) {

    // The screen has been locked 
    // do stuff...
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this. It gives if your device is locked/unlocked

```
KeyguardManager kgMgr = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
boolean showing = kgMgr.inKeyguardRestrictedInputMode();
```

Use a countdown timer and `onTick()` of that check this condition. `If` true stop timer/save the count `else` continue.

Comment: Thanks for your help and your suggestion for using count down timer.